# SQL как правильно связать внешний ключ?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

Пишу Андроид приложение, учет финансов, в данный момент делаю пункт переводов с кошелька на кошелек. Есть 3 Таблицы.

1. Таблица переводов. В ней есть 2 поля (`wallet_id_one, wallet_id_sec`) для внешних ключей (связывают эту таблицу с таблицей кошельков).
2. Таблица кошельков. Связана с таблицей "Валюта" и соответственно имеет поле для внешнего ключа с название `currency_id`.
3. Таблица валют.

Как сделать что бы в мой `ListView` в `tv_name_one` выводило имя кошелька именно из `wallet_id_one`, а в `tv_name_sec` выводило имя кошелька из `wallet_id_sec`?

Предполагаю что в формировании одного внешнего ключа должно быть несколько полей, но не уверен и не знаю как реализовать. Подскажите, если можно с примерами.

```
 String tableName = TABLE_TRANSFER_NAME + " inner join " + TABLE_WALLET_NAME + " on "
            + TABLE_TRANSFER_NAME + "." + TRANSFER_TABLE_WALLET_ID_ONE + " = "
            + TABLE_WALLET_NAME + "." + WALLET_TABLE_ID

            + " inner join " + TABLE_WALLET_NAME + " on "
            + TABLE_TRANSFER_NAME + "." + TRANSFER_TABLE_WALLET_ID_SEC + " = "
            + TABLE_WALLET_NAME + "." + WALLET_TABLE_ID

            + " inner join " + TABLE_CURRENCY_NAME + " on "
            + TABLE_WALLET_NAME + "." + WALLET_TABLE_CURRENCY_ID + " = "
            + TABLE_CURRENCY_NAME + "." + CURRENCY_TABLE_ID;

    String[] columsName = new String[]{TABLE_TRANSFER_NAME + "." + TRANSFER_TABLE_ID,
            TABLE_TRANSFER_NAME + "." + TRANSFER_TABLE_TXT,
            TABLE_TRANSFER_NAME + "." + TRANSFER_TABLE_SUMM,
            TABLE_CURRENCY_NAME + "." + CURRENCY_TABLE_SHORT_NAME,
            TABLE_WALLET_NAME + "." + WALLET_TABLE_NAME,
            TABLE_TRANSFER_NAME + "." + TRANSFER_TABLE_DATE,
            TABLE_TRANSFER_NAME + "." + TRANSFER_TABLE_WALLET_ID_ONE,
            TABLE_TRANSFER_NAME + "." + TRANSFER_TABLE_WALLET_ID_SEC};
 //Запрос
 cursor = mReadDB.query(tableName, columsName, null, null, null, null, null);
```

Ниже формирование курсора

```
private void setupTransferList() {
    db = new DB(this);
    // открываем подключение к БД
    Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG, "Transfer - setupTransferList - открываем подключение к БД");
    db.openRead();

    //Формируем столбцы сопоставления
    String[] from = new String[]{db.WALLET_TABLE_NAME, db.WALLET_TABLE_NAME, db.TRANSFER_TABLE_SUMM,
    db.CURRENCY_TABLE_SHORT_NAME, db.TRANSFER_TABLE_TXT,db.TRANSFER_TABLE_DATE};

    int[] to = new int[]{R.id.trans_wall_name_one, R.id.trans_wall_name_sec, R.id.trans_summ,
    R.id.trans_wall_curr, R.id.trans_txt, R.id.trans_date};

    // создаем адаптер и настраиваем список
    scAdapterTableTransfer = new SimpleCursorAdapter(Transfer.this, R.layout.item_transfer, null, from, to, 0);
    //Привязываем адаптер в Листу
    lvTtansfer.setAdapter(scAdapterTableTransfer);
    // добавляем контекстное меню к списку
    registerForContextMenu(lvTtansfer);
    // создаем лоадер для чтения данных
    loaderTransfer = getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(Constants.LOADER_ID_TABEL_TRANSFER, null, this);
}
```

При формировании курсора вопрос в массивах from и to, знаю что там ошибка в from, но не понимаю как правильно.
Сейчас кидает ошибку "Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: ambiguous column name: wallet.name_wallet (code 1)" - Не уникальное (не однозначное поле)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот код для sqlite:
Первая таблица

```
CREATE TABLE currency (cur_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, cur_name VARCHAR (40));
```

Вторая таблица

```
CREATE TABLE wallet (wal_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, wal_currency INTEGER REFERENCES currency (cur_id));
```

Третья таблица

```
CREATE TABLE remittance (wallet_id_one INTEGER REFERENCES wallet (wal_id), wallet_id_sec INTEGER REFERENCES wallet (wal_id), wallet_summa REAL);
```

А это сам запрос

```
select * from currency, remittance, wallet w1, wallet w2, currency cur1, currency cur2 where w1.wal_id=wallet_id_one and w2.wal_id=wallet_id_sec and w1.wal_currency=cur1.cur_id and w2.wal_currency=cur2.cur_id
```

Comment: Не до конца понял. Закинул свой код, можно на моем коде показать как это будет выглядеть?

Comment: @EvgeniyZaychenko ambiguous column name - такая ошибка возникает когда ты связываешь две таблицы в которых поля имеют одинаковые наименования. Ставь перед наименованием поля название таблицы (например nametable.namefield) и будет тебе счастье

Comment: Суть в том что таблица одна и та же и поле одно и тоже, просто нужна информация с разных ID, в одном запросе

Comment: Если вы про связь таблицы переводов с кошельком то вам надо два раза вязать с таблицей кошельком то есть как то так select перевод.кошелек_откуда, кошелек1.имя кошелька, перевод.кошелек_куда, кошелек2.имя кошелька from переводы, кошелек кошелек1, кошелек кошелек2 where перевод.кошелек_откуда=кошелек1.id and перевод.кошелек_куда=кошелек2.id

Comment: "или я тупой или лыжи не едут", дает ошибку...

Comment: Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "inner": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM transfer inner join wallet on transfer.wall_name_one = wallet.name_wallet where transfer.wall_id_one = wallet._id inner join wallet on transfer.wall_name_sec = wallet.name_wallet where transfer.wall_id_sec = wallet._id

Comment: Ну два раза where это сильно :) а зачем вам inner?

Comment: inner объединяет, на сколько знаю. Если б я все знал, то не спрашивал бы, я только учу, так что не глумитесь :). Я так и не допер. Мне нужно в запросе из каждого поля id_one и id_sec вытащить имя соответствующее кошельку с таким ИД и как-то вставить в ListView.

Comment: 1) если тебе надо жесткое объединение то достаточно использовать тот механизм что я тебе описал 2) лучше используй RecyclerView - он гибче 3) на твой вопрос про sql я дал ответ, и я не понимаю твоей логики когда ты то принимаешь ответ то нет.

Comment: Потому что он скорее всего правильный, но у меня не получается. Буду спрашивать по другому, спасибо.

Comment: @EvgeniyZaychenko можешь найти меня в скайпе oleg plesser и я там тебя проконсультирую

Answer (score 0):

У тебя должно быть два внешних ключа, оба на таблицу кошельков. А в ListView ты просто делаешь два JOIN'а с таблицей кошельков:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Currency](
[CurrencyId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[CurrencyName] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
[CurrencyCourse] [numeric](18, 4) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Currency] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
   ([CurrencyId] ASC)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Wallet](
[WalletId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[CurrencyId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[WalletName] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Wallet] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
   ([WalletId] ASC)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Wallet]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Wallet_Currency] FOREIGN KEY([CurrencyId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Currency] ([CurrencyId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Wallet] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Wallet_Currency]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Transactions](
[TransactionId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[WalletOneId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[WalletTwoId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[TransactionSum] [numeric](18, 4) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Transactions] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
   ([TransactionId] ASC)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Transactions]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Transactions_WalletOne] FOREIGN KEY([WalletOneId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Wallet] ([WalletId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Transactions] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Transactions_WalletOne]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Transactions]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Transactions_WalletTwo] FOREIGN KEY([WalletTwoId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Wallet] ([WalletId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Transactions] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Transactions_WalletTwo]
GO
```

А запрос для вьюшки будет примерно таким:

```
SELECT
    [W1].[WalletName] AS [Wallet 1], [W2].[WalletName] AS [Wallet 2]
FROM
    [dbo].[Transactions] AS [T]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    [dbo].[Wallet] AS [W1]
        ON [T].[WalletOneId] = [W1].[WalletId]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    [dbo].[Wallet] AS [W2]
        ON [T].[WalletTwoId] = [W2].[WalletId]
```

P.S. Код на T-SQL, но думаю понятен)

Comment: MS SQL под Android не живет, думаю ТС искал для SQLite. Хотя скрипты вполне универсальны - надо убрать `go`

Comment: Да, есть тонкости трансляции, но идея от этого не меняется. P.S. Под Android, думаю, можно также использовать MS SQL Compact